# Probability of at least three students having the same zodiac sign

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Q:

> There are $30$ students in a class. What is the probability that at least three of these
>   students have the same zodiac sign ($12$ signs)

I put the two variables in the question into sets $A$, $B$ and noted that their cardinalities:

$|A| = 30$, $|B| = 12$

And by the rule of counting functions I found that the number of ways of assigning a student a star sign to be $12^{30}$.

However I'm unsure what to use as the numerator and if this is the correct total to use for the denominator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could assign at most a group of 24 students to have exactly 2 signs in common. That means the 25th student must be given a sign already assigned to two other students.

Thus the probability of at least 3 students from a group of 30 having the same sign is 1, since it is unavoidable.

This called the pigeonhole principle and is a perfectly legitimate "mathematical" way to prove something.

UPDATE: Suppose there were only 20 students in the class. Then there are ways to assign zodiac signs to the students so that no sign is shared by more than 2 students. How many is the big question.

Think of filling 12 distinguishable bins (the zodiac signs) with 20 distinguishable balls (the students):

1.) I could fill 10 bins with 2 balls each, leaving 2 bins empty. There are $\binom{12}{10}$ ways to select the bins I fill and each choice can be filled $\frac{20!}{2!^{10}}$. Thus there are  $$\binom{12}{10}\cdot \frac{20!}{2^{10}}$$ ways I could fill 10 bins with 2 balls each.

2.) I could fill 9 bins with 2 balls each and 2 bins with 1 ball each, leaving 1 bin empty. There are $\binom{12}{9}$ ways to select the bins I fill with 2 balls and $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to choose the two bin I put 1 ball in. Each choice of 2 bins can be filled $\frac{20!}{2!}\frac{1}{2!^{9}}=\frac{20!}{2!^{10}}$ ways and each choice of single bins can be filled $2!$ ways. Thus there are  $$\binom{12}{9}\cdot \frac{20!}{2!^{10}}\cdot\binom{3}{2}\cdot 2!=\binom{12}{9}\cdot\binom{3}{2}\cdot\frac{20!}{2^{9}}$$ ways I could fill 9 bins with 2 balls each and 2 bins with 1 ball each, leaving 1 bin empty.

3.) I could fill 8 bins with 2 balls each and 4 bins with 1 ball each, leaving no bins empty. There are $\binom{12}{8}$ ways to select the bins I fill with 2 balls and with all the rest getting single balls. Each choice of 2 bins can be filled $\frac{20!}{4!}\frac{1}{2!^{8}}=\frac{20!}{4!\cdot 2!^{8}}$ ways and each choice of single bins can be filled $4!$ ways. Thus there are  $$\binom{12}{8}\cdot\frac{20!}{4!\cdot 2!^{8}}\cdot 4!=\binom{12}{8}\cdot\frac{20!}{2^{8}}$$ ways I could fill 9 bins with 2 balls each and 2 bins with 1 ball each, leaving 1 bin empty.

Thus the probability of any random arrangement have 3 or more students with the same zodiac sign is
$$
\frac{12^{20}-\left(\binom{12}{10}\cdot\frac{20!}{2^{10}}+\binom{12}{9}\cdot\binom{3}{2}\cdot\frac{20!}{2^{9}}+\binom{12}{8}\cdot\frac{20!}{2^{8}}\right)}{12^{20}}.
$$

Comment: But is this still the case with a smaller class size of e.g 20? If the probability for class size of 20 isn't 1 could you show how to calculate this?

Comment: If the class size is strictly smaller than twenty-four, then you count the number of ways that avoids assigning 1 zodiac sign to exactly 3 people. I will elaborate in an edit to my answer.

Comment: OK. Check out my edits.

Comment: Having some trouble understanding a few of the cases.. is there anyway you could put it in context of the students/zodiac signs?

Comment: The bins are the zodiac signs and the balls are the students.

Comment: Rather than looking at each individual student and deciding how to assign them a zodiac sign, I am thinking about how I can distribute the 20 students amongst the 12 zodiac signs so that no more than 2 students share a zodiac sign.

Answer (score 2):

Your choice of denominator is correct.

Firstly, if one looks at the problem, one may realize that this *must* occur.  Given twelve possible choices of zodiac sign, the maximum class size possible where only two or fewer students have the same zodiac sign is 12*2=**24**.  With a class larger than 24, every possible permutation must satisfy the given condition, resulting in a probability greater than or equal to 1.  There is no possible way to *not* satisfy the condition.

To show this mathematically:

**THE FOLLOWING METHOD IS INCORRECT, VIEW LAARS' ANSWER FOR MORE INFORMATION **

Given your choice of denominator, all you have do for the numerator is count the total number of ways that any three students could have the same sign.  Your logic should follow as such:

1. Choose which sign the three students have
2. Choose which three students have the chosen sign
3. It does not matter what the sign of the remaining 27 students have.

Number of possible signs: 12

Number of possible ways to choose three students: 30 choose 3

Number of possible ways to choose signs for the remaining 27 students: 12^27

Therefore your numerator should be

12 * (30 choose 3) * (12^27)

The value of this is greater than your denominator, resulting in a probability greater than one.  This is due to the fact that no permutation exists in which the given condition does not occur.  The condition is guaranteed to be satisfied always.

Comment: Is this still the case if I used a smaller class size? say 20? I input similar values and was still getting getting an answer > 0 I'm wondering if maybe you only add the remaining number of students rather than multiply? So the numerator would be 12 * (30C3) + 12^27. Or is this not possible? I just don't see how I'm still getting an answer > 0 with a smaller class size

Comment: I just tried it for a value of 20 and you're right, I made an error in my counting.  However, for the specific case of 30 classroom students, the probability will definitely be greater than or equal to one.  The addition method does not appear to be correct, however, as it returns a probability of less than one for this case.

Comment: I haven't figured out what the error is yet, however. I'll keep you updated if I do.